# How to do equivallent (not in expression) in regex when the expression in known

Tags: python, regex

(New to regex), I am facing difficulty in using a regex operation for not equal to.

I do something like :

```
re.findall("(<.*?>)", "i have a problem in doing <regex> for <not in> how can I do it")
```

Its giving me output like :

```
['<regex>', '<not in>']
```

I want to do the exact opposite, I want the output to be

```
[('i have a problem in doing'), ('for'), ('how can I do it')]
```

But somehow I cant crack the problem, A little help would appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `re.split` and instead of `.*?` its better to use negated character class `[^<]*` that refuse of match outer tokens :

```
>>> re.split("<[^<]*>", "i have a problem in doing <regex> for <not in> how can I do it")
['i have a problem in doing ', ' for ', ' how can I do it']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) instead:

```
>>> re.split("\s*<[^<]*>\s*", "i have a problem in doing <regex> for <not in> how can I do it")
['i have a problem in doing', 'for', 'how can I do it']
```

*Note that this removes leading and trailing whitespace characters as per your desired output.*

Comment: Thanks @vks, I am here to entertain! Actually, I "borrowed" Kasramvd's pattern so that it properly handles stings such as `"i had <a problem <with>"` for which the original pattern didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
print re.findall("(?:<.*?>)|([^<>]+)", "i have a problem in doing <regex> for <not in> how can I do it")
```

You can try this.If you dont want empty result do

```
print [i for i in re.findall("(?:<.*?>)|([^<>]+)", "i have a problem in doing <regex> for <not in> how can I do it") if i]
```